# Lack of value of QStringList in QT CDB Debug mode

Tags: c++, qt, debugging, visual-c++, qt-creator

I use QT 5.8 and QT Creator 4.2.2, MSVC2015 32bit compiller with CDB debugger from win10SDK kit. Debugging helper is enabled.
In debugging mode i can't see value of QString in QStringList, it shows d=0x1 and "Memory access error" in QArrayData struct. But single QString displayed well.

In case of using MinGW compiler with GDB debugger, QStringList displayed completly fine. But it need "*.a" library type for my project.
How to solve the problem?

lack of QStringList value PNG

[image]